# Cannot install any packages in R; broken "PATH"?

Tags: r

I was trying to fix an error I was getting when running a model in parallel in the brms package in R, and I think I accidentally changed the "PATH". Now I get an error every time I try to install any package. For example:

```
> install.packages('bbmle')
trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/bbmle_1.0.24.tgz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 885318 bytes (864 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 864 KB

/bin/sh: tar: command not found
Error: file ‘/var/folders/ff/jt7xp2c51dz_hkm71w4lp1p80000gn/T//RtmpyvfpeK/downloaded_packages/bbmle_1.0.24.tgz’ is not a macOS binary package
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system(paste0("tar zxf \"", path.expand(what), "\" -C \"", path.expand(where),  :
  error in running command
2: 'tar' returned non-zero exit code 127
```

I tried removing and re-installing R, but it didn't help. Here is what my path is currently set to

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/usr/bin;/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

I've spent hours searching to try to find what is going on and how to fix this, but I can't figure it out. I would really really appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance!!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2 tools_4.1.2
```

Comment: I suspect that the beginning (`"/usr/bin;/usr/bin`) is a problem.  These must be separated by colons (`:`), not semicolons (`;`).  Also, as you can see, `/usr/bin` was already there...

Comment: Thank you! I dropped the `/usr/bin;` and now it's working!!

Comment: Awesome -- these things happen, Sometimes we try too hard and mess something up -- so it is good to have a means of have someone look at it here.  Glad it worked out.